# After uploading app to testflight app is failed to load the CoreData

Tags: ios, xcode

I have recreated (Xcode project) old app with old bundle identifier with new CoreData Model from scratch. The app's CoreData works perfectly fine when I run it from Xcode. But after uploading it to testflight It stucks on the view controller where I load coreData. And it fails on loading. I am unable to see the exact reason as it is installed  via testflight so no logs are available.

Comment: Have you tried testing your app by plugging your phone into your mac and seeing if your CoreData works on a physical phone?

Comment: Rolled back because you have changed your question completely

Answer (score -1):

[Defined static constant (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IAS1.png)   AND
[static value mysteriously vanished (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbG2W.png)  
After observing the app behavior day and night, I have found that my app contains various static variable with which I use to share information among View Controller. **The mysterious behavior of static variable caused the halting of the whole app.** I have found that static variable (even static constants) losses its values at the time of execution. To fix this static data loss problem I have replaced all static variable with NSUserdefault. And now every think is working fine. The strange thing is when I executed app from Xcode It was working perfectly fine and when I downloaded from test-flight ; It started abnormal behaviour. Some time ago I also have noticed that this thing even happened in Xcode local build. **Is the apple doing something with static data for memory management ?**